# Extracting Data With Regular Expressions

Tags: python-3.x

Actual data: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_285094.txt (There are 83 values and the sum ends with 782)

I need the answer to this question guys :) please help

Enter the sum from the actual data and your Python code below:
Sum: ends with 782)

```
import re

hand = open("regex_sum_24962.txt")
x=list()
for line in hand:
     y = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
     x = x+y

sum=0
for z in x:
    sum = sum + int(z)

print(sum)
```

No file can find (problem)

Answer (score 0):

Check filename or path to file.

(regex_sum_285094.txt  in link and regex_sum_24962.txt in code).